# Get the file type of a file using the Windows API

Tags: winapi

I am trying to identify when a file is PNG or JPG to apply it as a wallpaper. I am using the `SHGetFileInfo` to get the type name with the `.szTypeName` variable, but I just realized that it changes if the OS is in another language.

This is my code:

```
SHFILEINFOW fileInfo;
UINT sizeFile = sizeof(fileInfo);
UINT Flags = SHGFI_TYPENAME | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES;

//  Getting file info to find out if it has JPG or PNG format
SHGetFileInfoW(argv[1], 0, &fileInfo, sizeFile, Flags);
```

This is how I am validating:

```
if (wcscmp(fileInfo.szTypeName, L"JPG File") == 0)
{

//Code here

}
```

When the OS is in spanish, the value changes to "Archivo JPG" so I would have to validate against all language, and does not make sense.

Any idea what other function I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This API is meant to be used to produce a user-facing string representation for known file types<sup>1)</sup>. It is not meant to be used to implement code logic.

More importantly, it doesn't try to parse the file **contents**. It works off of the file extension alone. If you rename an Excel workbook *MySpreadsheet.xlsx* to *MySpreadsheet.png*, it will happily report, that this is a *"PNG File"*.

The solution to your problem is simple: You don't have to do anything, other than filtering on the file extension. Use [PathFindExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathfindextensionw) (or [PathCchFindExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pathcch/nf-pathcch-pathcchfindextension) for Windows 8 and above) to get the file extension from a fully qualified path name.

This can fail, in case the user appended the wrong file extension. Arguably, this isn't something your application should fix, though.

---

As an aside, you pass `SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES` to `SHGetFileInfoW` but decided to not pass any [file attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-attribute-constants) (second argument) to the call. This is a bug. See [What does SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES mean?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040601-00/?p=39073) for details.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *It is the moral equivalent of `SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME`. [The only thing you can do with display names is display them](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070313-00/?p=27643).*

Comment: Thanks for answering! That was all I needed. I used `PathFindExtension` (`PWSTR findExt = PathFindExtensionW(argv[1])` function and deleted all the `SHGetFileInfoW` code.